# Prove $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I am trying to prove that the following sum equals to zero:
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=0$$
This actually surprised me a-lot. Usually when these kinds of infinite sums equal to zero, it's because of some sort of symmetry, or something like that. But I can't see it here. The $n=0$ term isn't zero, and we don't have $n\mapsto -n$ symmetry. The only thing I thought of is that maybe the Taylor series of $\arctan(x)$ might help, but the sum there starts from $n=1$ (or $n=0$ if you look at $\arctan(x)/x^2$), and needs to be integrated. It was kind of complicated (maybe it's not and I missed something).

P.S. - The original thing I need to compute is the following integral $I$, which I proved that is connected to the mentioned sum through the Residue Theorem:

$$I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{i\theta}\sec{(e^{-i\theta})}\text{d}\theta=\frac 8\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}=0$$

I added this because maybe the integral might be useful somehow (maybe easier to compute). Again I searched for symmetry (the integrand is clearly $2\pi$ symmetric, so I changed the integration interval to be $[-\pi,\pi]$, and then hoped that the integrand would be odd or something. But it's not, if I'm not mistaken).

Thanks

Comment: Write down the terms for $n=-3, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3$ and you'll see quickly which terms cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, $I=-i\oint_{|z|=1}z^{-2}\sec zdz=0$ because $\sec z$ has no poles in the contour, and the $z^{-2}$ factor doesn't contribute either. (The $-$ sign comes from the contour being clockwise.)

Comment: Oh my goodness. I feel dumb. To think that my mistake was that I substituted $z=e^{i\theta}$ instead of $z=e^{-i\theta}$... A very imporant minus there. Thanks a lot. And yes, I can see that the residue of $z=0$ is zero (since the integrand is even).

Answer (score 2):

Let us check some terms:

- For $n=-1$ and $n=0$ we get the terms of the series:
  $$
  \frac{(-1)^{-1}}{(-2+1)^2}=-\frac 1{1^2}
  \text{ and }
  \frac{(-1)^{0}}{(0+1)^2}=+\frac 1{1^2}\ .
  $$
- For $n=-2$ and $n=1$ we get the terms of the series:
  $$
  \frac{(-1)^{-2}}{(-4+1)^2}=+\frac 1{3^2}
  \text{ and }
  \frac{(-1)^{1}}{(2+1)^2}=-\frac 1{3^2}\ .
  $$
- For $n=-3$ and $n=2$ we get the terms of the series:
  $$
  \frac{(-1)^{-3}}{(-6+1)^2}=-\frac 1{5^2}
  \text{ and }
  \frac{(-1)^{2}}{(4+1)^2}=+\frac 1{5^2}\ .
  $$
- For $n=-4$ and $n=3$ we get the terms of the series:
  $$
  \frac{(-1)^{-4}}{(-8+1)^2}=+\frac 1{7^2}
  \text{ and }
  \frac{(-1)^{3}}{(6+1)^2}=-\frac 1{7^2}\ .
  $$
  The cancelling scheme should be clear now.

Comment: This is justified because the sum is *absolutely* convergent, right? Because it feels a bit like $1-1+1-1+1-1\cdots$...

Comment: Yes, the justification should be a part of the OP, to have a well defined object. In fact, the sum of the absolute values is $$2\left(\frac 1{1^2}+\frac 1{3^2}+\frac 1{5^2}+\dots\right)=2\cdot\frac 18\pi^2\ ,$$which can be obtained from $$\frac 1{1^2}+\frac 1{2^2}+\frac 1{3^2}+\frac 1{4^2}+\frac 1{5^2}+\frac 1{6^2}+\dots=\frac 16\pi^2$$by splitting out multiplicatively the Euler factor corresponding to the prime $2$.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot the summands:
[image]
So evidence suggests there are opposing terms, it's just that they're symmetric about $n=-1/2$ not $n=0$. Symbolically,
$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}.$$
Now just change the index of the first sum,
$$-\sum_{n=-\infty}^0\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n-1)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2}.$$
Hopefully you can see why this equals zero now.

Comment: That's great, just an index change $n\mapsto -n$ of the first sum and that's it. I'm upset that I missed that, because I tried to do exactly that before I posted the question. Thanks

Comment: @AmitZach yes, if you make $n\mapsto -n$ then $(-1)^{-n}=(-1)^n$ and $(-2n-1)^2=(2n+1)^2$ and the limits of the summation are $\infty$ and $0$ so you get $-S+S=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty{(-1)^n\over(2n+1)^2}=\sum_{m\equiv1\text{ mod }4}{1\over m^2}-\sum_{m\equiv3\text{ mod }4}{1\over m^2}$$

and $m\equiv1$ mod $4$ if and only if $-m\equiv3$ mod $4$, so, since $m^2=(-m)^2$, the two sums on the right hand side are equal, hence cancel each other out.

Comment: Really nice to see so many different approaches for the same problem, one vying with another for elegance. Hats off to all the great answers and insight. Really enjoyable!!

Comment: @LawrenceMano Couldn't agree more!